# API to read Daily Active Users from Firebase Authentication in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I've been searching online how to display daily active users from Firebase and use it in a Flutter app. I haven't found any solution for it.

I did some experiment with Firebase Analytics but the only thing that came out of that was, I was able to see x many people have been active in the last 30 min on the Project Overview.
I don't have any fields in my users collection that has active/inactive or anything like that.
I just need to display the same data as can be seen in the Authentication => Usage (Daily Active Users). Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is currently no public API to read the daily active users from Firebase Authentication. It sounds reasonable though, so I recommend filing a feature request with the [Firebase support team](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) or on [firebase.uservoice.com](https://firebase.uservoice.com).